# visual studio mvc 5 creating table with data from different models/tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I recently started using the vs mvc 5 framework and most tutorials say how to use a single data source for a table in a view, I however would like to make a table in a view which takes data from 2-3 different tables and connects them together, I tried doing it basing on some questions on stackoverflow etc. but nothing seems to works.

There are 3 tables: Contattis, Companies and Contacts, the first one is an sql server table connected with visual studio as .edmx, the last 2 are models created in the application and seeded through it. I want to connect them based on Contact ID.

right at this moment this is the code:

Model:

```
namespace ContactManager.Models
{
public partial class ContattiDB2 : DbContext
{
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ContactManager.Models.Contatti> Contatti { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ContactManager.Models.ContactsUni2> ContactsUni2 { get; set; }
}

public partial class ContactsUnified
{
    //these are the 3 tables I want to use
    public IEnumerable<Contatti> Contattis { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

}
```

Companies:

```
namespace ContactManager.Models
{
public class Companies
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCity { get; set; }
    public string CompanyState { get; set; }
    public string CompanyZip { get; set; }
    public string CompanyArea { get; set; }
}
}
```

Contacts:

```
namespace ContactManager.Models
{
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace ContactManager.Controllers
{
public class ContactsUnifiedController : Controller
{
    private ContattiDB2 db2 = new ContattiDB2();
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: ContactsUnified
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        /*var contacts = db.Contacts.ToList();
        var companies = db.Companies.ToList();
        var contatti = db2.Contattis.ToList();
        var view = new ContactsUnified()
        {
            Contacts = contacts,
            Companies = companies,
            Contattis = contatti
        };
        return View(view);*/

        var viewModel = new ContactsUni2();
        viewModel.Contattis = db.Contattis
            .Include(i => i.ContattoID);
        viewModel.Contacts = db.Contacts;
        viewModel.Companies = db.Companies;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The view (This method doesn't work, it says "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ContactManager.Models.ContactsUnified', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ContactManager.Models.ContactsUnified]'." Though even if it did work I doubt it would display the 3 tables data as required)

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactManager.Models.ContactsUnified>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Contacts Unified</h2>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Nome)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Citta)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.ContattoID)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.CodicePostale)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Email)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.Address)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.CompanyId)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.ContactId)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName)

        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contatti.Nome)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contatti.Citta)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contatti.ContattoID)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contatti.CodicePostale)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contatti.Email)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact.Address)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact.CompanyId)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact.ContactId)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company.CompanyName)

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ContattoID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ContattoID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ContattoID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: What is the relationship between those three tables

Comment: Contatti and Contacts describe the contacts personal info and should be Connecticut through ContactId (one to one), contacts are Connected to companies through companyid (many to one)

Comment: Are you looking for immediate answer? If not I'll help you in sometime. Need to work on this. is that okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are required to pass an IEnumerable list from the Index controller, as your view is expecting an `IEnumerable<ContactManager.Models.ContactsUnified>` list.

In your Index controller try this

```
public ActionResult Index(String Page)
{
ContactsUnified CU = new ContactsUnified();
CU.Contattis = db.Contattis.Include(i => i.ContattoID);
CU.Contacts = db.Contacts;
CU.Companies = db.Companies;
List<ContactsUnified> contactlist = new List<ContactsUnified>();
contactlist.Add(CU);
return View(contactlist.AsEnumerable());
}
```

Then in view you can access these items as

```
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Nome)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Citta)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.ContattoID)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.CodicePostale)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Email)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.Address)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.CompanyId)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.ContactId)
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName)

    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

But when applying loop it is different than usual i.e you have to apply a loop.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
for (int i = 0; i < @item.Contatti.Count(); i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
        @item.Contatti[i].Nome
        @item.Contatti[i].Citta
        @item.Contatti[i].ContattoID
        @item.Contatti[i].CodicePostale
        @item.Contatti[i].Email
        @item.Contatti[i].Address
        @item.Contatti[i].CompanyId
        @item.Contatti[i].ContactId
        @item.Contatti[i].CompanyName

    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Contatti[i].ContattoID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { item.Contatti[i].ContattoID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { item.Contatti[i].ContattoID })
    </td>
</tr>
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm trying to apply it but i'm getting an error in controller at this line: contactlist.Add(CU.AsEnumerable()); at the 'CU' part It says that: 'ContactsUnified' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataTable)' requires a receiver of type 'DataTable'. I get a similar error for Contatti.Count() in the View

Comment: I'm sorry it was contactlist.Add(CU); and after that return View(contactlist.AsEnumerable());

Comment: @Dantuzzo ....I somehow mixed two lines in the end of Index controller. I have edited it. Hope it works now. Earlier it didn't work because it was trying to convert the ContactUnified object CU into an Enumerable list which is not possible therefore the solution is to add this object into a ContactUnified list contactlist.Add(CU); and then send it to View as Enumerable list return View(contactlist.AsEnumerable());